# Encoding, Decoding Pinyin Characters in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I'm having trouble en-/decoding Pinyin characters from an excel file.

The structure of that file looks like this:

[image]

[...]

and I want to store the values of each column in a separate variable doing it like this: (for Pinyin I need to pass *'ignore'* argument)

```
df = pd.read_excel("static\\voc1.xlsx")

#English doesn't actually need en-/decoding
en = str(df['English'][:3]).encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
zh = str(df['Chinese'][:3]).encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
pinyin = str(df['Pinyin'][:3]).encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252', 'ignore')

print(zh, en, pinyin)
```

which results in the following when executing:

```
0     我
1    我们
2     你
Name: Chinese, dtype: object
0     I, me
1    we, us
2       you
Name: English, dtype: object
0       wǒ
1    wǒmen
2       n�
Name: Pinyin, dtype: object
```

As you can see this acutally works for Chinese characters and English, but for Pinyin it is either showing this 'diamond questionmark' for some characters or throwing an error if I don't pass an *errors* argument:

```
df = pd.read_excel("static\\voc1.xlsx")

#English doesn't actually need en-/decoding
en = str(df['English'][:3]).encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
zh = str(df['Chinese'][:3]).encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
pinyin = str(df['Pinyin'][:3]).encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')

print(zh, en, pinyin)
```

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 34: character maps to <undefined>
```

If you want to reproduce yourself:
I'm using this file here: https://www.mandarinzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/HSK1-Vocabulary-List.xlsx

on Win10 64-bit with Visual Studio Code

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem.
I was running it through VS 'Code Runner' extension which caused the error. I guess it is possible to configure it somehow to make it work, but for the moment I just use standard terminal within VS Code or run it directly through CLI.